# Can't change stacking order of images with z-index

Tags: html, jquery-ui

If I place two images on a page and make them draggable I'm unable to change the stacking order with z-index:

```
<img class='dragme'  src='http://s20.postimg.org/bixp6bh0p/clown.jpg' />
<img class='dragme' src='http://s20.postimg.org/ddh45wqnd/t_cateye.jpg ' />
```

That is, the cateye is always on top of the clown regardless of the z-indexes assigned. See http://jsfiddle.net/XQbLR/3/.

But if I put the images in divs (bottom images with red border) then I am able to change the stacking order with the z-indexes assigned to the divs.

Does anyone understand what's going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to give your images the appropriate `id`s referenced in your CSS definitions.

```
<img class='dragme' id="clown" src='http://s20.postimg.org/bixp6bh0p/clown.jpg' />
<img class='dragme' id="cateye" src='http://s20.postimg.org/ddh45wqnd/t_cateye.jpg ' />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XQbLR/4/